# How can i prepare seperated pages report with rdlc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, reporting, rdlc

I can take student report in one page. (with rdlc and report viewer component) 
But i want to take every studets information sperated pages.

How can i do this?

I didnt find any things about this on internet.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click on the row group, properties.  Check the option on the left for page breaks.  right side of screen has checkbox to break between each group.

This is all under the assumption you already have your report "Group" by some student id.